# Clang++ cannot find GL/glu.h, but g++ (mingw-w64) works correctly

Tags: c++, opengl, clang++, glew, glu

I am making a OpenGL wrapper in C++ and modern OpenGL. So in my main header I have the following includes

```cpp
#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU
#ifdef _WIN32
    #define GLFW_DLL
#endif

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
```

And compile with this command through a makefile:
`g++ <all sources> -g -o main.exe  -L"D:/cpp_libraries/glfw-3.3.5-compiled/src" -L"D:/cpp_libraries/glew-2.1.0-compiled/lib" -lglfw3 -lglew32 -lopengl32 -I"./include" -I"D:/cpp_libraries/glfw-3.3.5-source/include" -I"D:/cpp_libraries/glew-2.1.0-source/include" -I"D:\cpp_libraries\glm" -std=c++2a -Wall`

This works correctly. Then I tried switching `g++` to `clang++` for compilation and now there is an error on line 1205 in glew.h:
`glew.h:1205:14: fatal error: 'GL/glu.h' file not found`

After a google search I found out I really shouldn't need `glu`. I tried adding a `#define GLEW_NO_GLU` before the inclusion of `glew`, all that does is make `glfw3.h` throw the same error. I also tried removing the `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU` and that somehow made clang fail to find libraries like `iostream` and `chrono`. Neither of these changes had any effect on the compilation with `gcc`.

This is my first time using `clang` and I really hope that I have not done some elementary mistake in assuming it is too similar to `gcc`

Comment: Please show the full error message with the info where GL/glu.h is includes from.

Comment: `GL/glu.h` is part of the Windows SDK. A mingw distribution typically comes with all standard windows include files. However, why do you even force glu inclusion by `#define GLFW_INCLUDE_GLU`? Your mingw command line shows that you don't even link `glu32`, so your project doesn't need that (deprecated, completely outdated) library at all.

Comment: @derhass I know I should not need it, I tried to remove it and nothing changed. I had just copied it from the glfw tutorial before switching to modern GL. So what you're saying is that I just have to compile glu and add it as a library?

Comment: @273K
In file included from ./src/camera.cpp:1:
In file included from ./include\camera.h:3:
D:/cpp_libraries/glew-2.1.0-source/include\GL/glew.h:1205:14: fatal error: 'GL/glu.h' file not found
#    include <GL/glu.h>
             ^~~~~~~~~~
This same error message is generated wherever I have included glew.

Comment: Open GL is a part of Windows SDK. You do not need all those 3rd libraries in D:/cpp_libraries/. If you remove them you will move forward.

Comment: As the error message clearlu shows, `glew.h` also includes `glu.h` (for no apperent reason, though), but you can `#define GLEW_NO_GLU` before including `glew.h` to prevent this. GLEW itself has a few really weird design choice, and I don't really recommend using it at all, though.

Comment: @derhass I did exactly that. It was the first thing I did and I described that in the question. If ```glew.h``` does not include glu, then ```glfw3.h``` tries to do the same and fails. If I also tell glfw not to include glu, the error messages show that some of STD fails to be included. I assume that I have actually fixed the GL problem, but my clang installation is not correctly set up and fails to load STD.

Comment: I think your conslusions are all wrong - it's not that including `glu.h` makes it to magically find `iostream` or `chrono`, it's just that not finding `glu.h` will make it error out before it even tries to search for the former.